# How to make input field or textarea with emoji-picker in angular?

Tags: html, angular, emoji

new-status.component.ts

```
<mat-form-field>
  <textarea matInput placeholder="Status Content" style="height: 200px;"></textarea>
  <emoji-mart title="Pick your emoji…" emoji="point_up"></emoji-mart>
</mat-form-field>
```

i follow this link for solution(https://github.com/TypeCtrl/ngx-emoji-mart), now i want put emoji picker in input field or textarea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

let's begin by

```
npm install @ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart
```

then,

```
import { PickerModule } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart'
```

add the stylesheet in angular.json:

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "../node_modules/@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/picker.css"
        ],
```

add the module in the imports array of app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
...,
imports:      [ ..., PickerModule, ... ],
...
})
```

finally add for testing to see if all work in app.component.html :

```
<emoji-mart title="Pick your emoji…" emoji="point_up"></emoji-mart>
```

That's it :-)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxanqx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**EDIT**

There is a raw approach you need to stylisize.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxanqx

you have a textarea a button to add an emoticon to your text.

let me know if it's a good way for you to start :-)

Comment: Link points to some other problem statement. Please provide updated link. The emoji along with input

Comment: please provide your updated link. The link points to somewhere irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I've found this example on StackBlitz (angular 8 and ngx-emoji-mart 1.0.8, but it's working the same with last versions): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emojis

Comment: @CirrusMinor I've used the emoji-mart library same as in the example link you shared, the picker opens without any emojiis and after few seconds crashes... any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 6):

I know its late but maybe someone else could use it.

I have improved those available solutions.
emoji should be inserted on carrot position, and we should be able to undo ,redo on message box
here is solution.

HTML

```
 <textarea #input [formControl]="message" (keydown.enter)="send()"> </textarea>
    
    <emoji-mart
       title="Pick your emoji…"
       (emojiSelect)="addEmoji($event)"
       [hideObsolete]="true"
       [isNative]="true">
    </emoji-mart>
```

TS

```
    addEmoji(selected: Emoji) {
            const emoji: string = (selected.emoji as any).native;
            const input = this.input.nativeElement;
            input.focus();
        
            if (document.execCommand){ // document.execCommand is absolute but it //add support for undo redo and insert emoji at carrot position
//any one has better solution ?
    
              var event = new Event('input');
              document.execCommand('insertText', false, emoji);
              return; 
            }
               // insert emoji on carrot position
            const [start, end] = [input.selectionStart, input.selectionEnd]; 
            input.setRangeText(emoji, start, end, 'end');
          }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install @ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart
```

then in your module.ts

```
import { PickerModule } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart'
```

add its style in your styles.scss

```
@import '~@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/picker';
```

in your component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="emojiForm">
   <emoji-mart (emojiClick)="addEmoji($event)" emoji="point_up"></emoji-mart>
   <textarea type="text" formControlName="inputField"></textarea>
</form>
```

in you component.ts

```
addEmoji($event){
  let data = this.emojiForm.get('inputField');
  data.patchValue(data.value + $event.emoji.native)
}
```

Comment: This solution will always append the emoji to the back of the input text field.  Probably OP wants to be able to insert emoji at the current caret position.

Answer (score 2):

[document.execCommand() is now deprecated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

I have an alternative solution to your problem, which takes into consideration current caret position.  The only downside is that it wipes undo/redo history.

Emoji html:

```
<emoji-mart *ngIf="showEmojiWindow"
            [showPreview]="false"
            (emojiClick)="addEmoji($event)"
            [isNative]="true"
            [showSingleCategory]="true"
            [emojiTooltip]="true"></emoji-mart>
```

Form html:

```
<form [formGroup]="sendMessageForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(sendMessageForm)">
    <input #messageInput type="text" name="message" formControlName="message" class="form-control">
</form>
```

Typescript:

```
@ViewChild('messageInput')
messageInput: ElementRef;
sendMessageForm: FormGroup;
private messageFormControl: FormControl;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildSendMessageForm();
}

addEmoji(event: EmojiEvent): void {
    this.messageInput.nativeElement.focus();
    const selectionStart = this.messageInput.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    const currentValue = this.messageInput.nativeElement.value;
    const newValue = currentValue.substring(0, selectionStart) + event.emoji.native + currentValue.substring(selectionStart);
    this.messageFormControl.setValue(newValue);
    // the following 2 lines set the caret position behind the emoji
    this.messageInput.nativeElement.selectionStart = selectionStart + event.emoji.native.length;
    this.messageInput.nativeElement.selectionEnd = selectionStart + event.emoji.native.length;
    this.showEmojiWindow = false;
}

private buildSendMessageForm(): void {
    this.messageFormControl = new FormControl('');
    this.sendMessageForm = new FormGroup({
        message: this.messageFormControl
    });
}
```